# How can I prevent to re-sizing of div when user enters text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/arxoq7oq/68/

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-heigth: 10em;
}

.item-list1 {
  display:table-cell;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-heigth: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-heigth: 10em;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  overflow:scroll;
  resize: vertical;
  /* Does nothing with table-cell*/ 
}
```

```html
  <body>
      <div class="container green" contenteditable="true">
        <div class="item-list1">
          <div class="item">Item 1</div>
          <div class="item">
Item 2 mighdt wrap to multiple linesddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

As you can see on the upper example, I want to use vertical-alignment and scroll at the same time in the div-textarea.

In this example, if user enters text into the div(contenteditable), the size of div will be expanded to the below.
What I really want to know is like following.

**Questions**: I just want to expand the scroll bar, not the size of div. Is there any possible way to implement this?

Comment: The main problem is with the `display:table`. You can use `vertical-alight` without it. Maybe show us the relevant code that actually uses the `vertical-align`. I mean, in your code, I can't see why do you need it.

Comment: By changing `table-cell` to `block` you can achieve what you're seeking

Comment: I have 3-buttons to change vertical-alignment if user wants. #Mosh Feu

Comment: #vivekkupadhyay But if I do so, the vertical-alignment doen't work. You can test it by deleting the text as much as you can see the whole text without scrolll.

Comment: btw, typo in css: min-heig**th**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing `table-cell` to `block` you can achieve what you're seeking as:

### Code Snippet

```css
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  min-height: 10em;
}
.item-list1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container green" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="item-list1">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Quisque gravida sit amet dolor.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I do so, the vertical-align doesn't work at all. Can I have another answer?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for your help. It's a pretty much helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vhLenb5/)

```
.item{
    height: 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You just need to add this to your css.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 10em;
}

.item-list1 {
  display:table-cell;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  max-width: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 10em;
  vertical-align:bottom;

  resize: vertical;
}

.item{
  height:1em;
  overflow-y: scroll;  
}
```

```html
  <div class="container green" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="item-list1">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2 mighdt wrap to multiple linesddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: But the scroll looks a bit weird. Can I have another option?

Comment: typo in css in your fiddle: *-heig**th**, fixed it in the snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes in your css as below and it will work perfect:

```
.container {
width:10em;
height:10em;
max-width: 10em;
max-height: 10em;
min-width: 10em;
min-heigth: 10em;
}

.item-list1 {
width:10em;
height:10em;
max-width: 10em;
max-heigth: 10em;
min-width: 10em;
min-heigth: 10em;
vertical-align:bottom;
overflow:scroll;
resize: vertical;
}
```

Hope this helps. Donot forget to mark as answer and add reputtion if this worked as u required.

Comment: If I do so, the vertical-align doesn't work at all. Can I have another answer?